# Why can't use iterators with template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want to traverse a vector but I don't know it's type before hand.So,I do the following : -

```
template<typename T>
vector<int> sas_v(vector<T>vT,T val)
    {
      vector<int>il; //index_list
      vector<T>::iterator it;
      for(it = vT.begin();it!=vT.end();it++)

          {
             if(*it==val)
             il.push_back(it-vT.begin()); //0 based indexing
          }

      return il;
   }
```

But I get bunch of errors.Though if I do this following way it works,Why?

```
template<typename T>
vector<int> sas_v(vector<T>vT,T val)
{
    vector<int>il; //index_list
//    vector<T>::iterator it;
   // for(it = vT.begin();it!=vT.end();it++)
    for(int a=0;a<vT.size();a++)
    {
        if(vT[a]==val)
            il.push_back(a); //0 based indexing
    }

    return il;
}
```

Comment: use `typename vector<T>::iterator it;`

Comment: If you say "I get bunch of errors", what errors do you mean? In the future, please also post the error messages!

Comment: If you have a new enough compiler, just use `auto`.  The pain of getting iterator types properly declared inside template functions was one of the flaws in C++ as a language.  It is a flaw that has been fixed.  If stuck with an older compiler, others already told you about the use of `typename`